# Unread indicator for Slack Chrome App

Tags: unity, launcher, google-chrome, icons, indicator

I'm using Slack as an application shortcut through Google Chrome. It appears that unity uses the web's favicon for the launcher icon, which is neat. However, it seems to cache the icon for an unknown (to me) time.

Slack uses javascript to change its favicon to indicate if you have unread messages. It doesn't seem that Unity gets the memo from the web app, and just keeps the default icon.

Is there a way to regularly refresh the launcher icon? Or is there another clever solution to monitor Slack and have an indication as to whether or not I have unread messages? I'm getting the Desktop notifications that let me know I have a new @mention or PM, but if I walk away for a second, I may not notice that I have unread messages.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Slack has now a nice official client for Ubuntu and RPM distributions.

Download it from the official page: https://slack.com/downloads/linux

It'll automatically insert a `slack.list` entry in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`, so you'll receive updates during an `apt` update.

Comment: Convenient to find you, the author here! I installed scudcloud, but when setting it up, I accidentally typed the wrong team settings into your app, so it doesn't match my slack account, but it does match someone else's. I can't find a way to start over. I've even used `apt-get remove --purge` followed by a re-install, no joy. Any advice?

Comment: @Marc: remove the `~/.scudcloud` file :)

Comment: Great work, thanks so much. My team just started using Slack out of the blue yesterday, and I was so annoyed that there was no integrated app for Ubuntu.

Comment: @isherwood I've updated the answer to point to the official client.

Comment: ... which doesn't notify like the Windows client does, using taskbar flashing. At least it doesn't for me, and I'm not clever enough to figure out how to make it do so.